# what is the difference between IIS default website vs web application about performance/speed?

Tags: iis

trying to deploy application in iis, but I am not sure about the speed if I add website in default websites and what if we add it in new application ? someone can suggest regarding this what will be the difference about the performance

Comment: No difference IMHO.

Comment: Does not make any difference. There is no difference in the performance of all sites in IIS, including the default site. The default site is just an ordinary site with port 80 enabled, it has nothing special.